# R: How to use a vector item as a name for a list item

Tags: r

I am trying to build a dictionary of words that are close to each other in a body of text.

Let's say I have this:

```
> words
 [1] "thanks"  "fish"   "long"
```

Then I would like to be able to do something like this (within an `apply` construct):

```
dictionary$words[i] <- words[-i]
```

and end up with this:

```
> dictionary
$thanks
[1] "fish" "long"

$fish
[1] "thanks" "long"  

$long
[1] "thanks" "fish"
```

I tried with `assign` but I couldn't get it right and I'm not even sure if that's the way to go.

Comment: I would go with `combn(words, length(words)-1, FUN=function(x) list(x))` since `words` will not always be three words long but yes, this works very well.

Comment: You don't need the anonymous function call. just `list` will be enough.

Comment: Agreed. I forgot to mention that the list elements will not have names if you choose this solution. But still it's useful to find out that `combn` exists.

Comment: I noticed that after I posted it as a solution and then deleted for the same reason.  ColonelBeauvel's solution is pretty good and compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
setNames(lapply(words, function(u) words[words!=u]), words)

#$thanks
#[1] "fish" "long"

#$fish
#[1] "thanks" "long"  

#$long
#[1] "thanks" "fish"
```

Comment: Awesome! I wouldn't have thought of this in a hundred years.